# Alias within a class template

Tags: c++

For following class

```
template<typename T>
class test { 
   public:
   using unit = std::micro;    
};
```

How do I access unit like `test::unit` without having to specify the template argument or make it a template alias. Please note that inserting a dummy template argument like e.g . int is not an option since some template classes cannot be instantiated with such types.

Comment: you move it out of the template

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why is it a member of the template when you do not want/need to instantiate the template to access it?

Comment: A general approach you can take is to create a common base class from which the template classes inherit, `template<typename T> class Test : public TestBase`, and then put everything they have in common in the base class.

Comment: in a nutshell, `template<typename T>` means "everything that follows depends on `T`"

Comment: If you want do not want it in the enclosing namespace, move it to a non-templated baseclass, e.g. `test_defs` and then `test` can inherit from it.

Comment: Place the `using` directive within the namespace of the template. Then if your other classes are in the same namespace, you can utilise the value.

Comment: `struct common_test_definitions { using unit = std::micro; };` `template<typename T> class test : public common_test_definitions { ... };` ...  but I agree. It feels like an XY problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it is important to understand that really everything in the template depends on the template parameter `T`. Even if it looks like it does not on first sight.

Consider that there can be a specialization:

```
template <>
struct foo< bar > {};
```

Now there is a `foo` instantiation that has no member alias. And thats the reason why `foo::unit` cannot work the way you wish.

---

> Please note that inserting a dummy template argument like e.g . int is not an option since some template classes cannot be instantiated with such types.

I don't understand this argument. If there is a different class template (there are no template classes, they are called class templates) which cannot be instantiated with `int` then choose a different default. You need not use the same default for all.

However, as discussed above the approach with using a default argument and then refering to the alias via `foo<>::unit` is flawed anyhow.

---

The simple solution is to not have the alias as member:

```
using unit = std::micro;    
template<typename T> class test { };
```

On the other hand, if it should be part of the class, it can be moved to a non-template base class:

```
struct base { using unit = std::micro; }
template <typename T> struct test : base {};
```